# VBA returning different results between setting breakpoint and running without

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a module to fix overlapping dataLabels in a chart in Excel.  Since it is to be used in a macro that loops through 200 files, updating the numbers for the chart each time, it has to be done via VBA.

When I am testing it, if I simply call the "fixPieLabels" sub from my `testChart` sub, it gives the desired results.  If I have a breakpoint on the line that calls "fixPieLabels", as well as on the "next x" line (so I can check each iteration) from the `testAll` sub that loops through different sets of values, it gives the desired results.  If I only have a breakpoint on the "next x" line after the fixPieLabels call, it gives wrong results.

I thought the chart wasn't updating in time for the "fixPieLabels" sub, but I added some debug.print statements to find out where it was off...and I have the same values for all pertinent variables between the "off" runs and the "correct" runs, including the same section of the if/else condition being run, but somehow it is calculating differently.

For example, here is the debug printout of a wrong test:

```
Fixed Income Investments
height: 25.5312598425197
percSide: 0.45 gT: 82.5076377952756 gH: 153.454803149606
40%-<60%
postTop: 153.09811023622
```

And the correct test:

```
Fixed Income Investments
height: 25.5312598425197
percSide: 0.45 gT: 82.5076377952756 gH: 153.454803149606
40%-<60%
postTop: 138.796692913386
```

Here is the calculation it is running:

```
currLabel.Top = gT - currLabel.Height / 2 + percSide * gH
```

As you see, all the variables are the same, but in the "wrong" run, the `currLabel.Top` after running the calculation ("postTop") is mathematically incorrect.  And in other tests, I had it print the `currLabel.Top` before running the calculation, and it is changing, so the problem is not that it simply hasn't assigned the new top.

Here are the subs calling the "fixPieLabels" sub:

```
Private Sub testChart()
    fixPieLabels ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)
End Sub

Private Sub testAll()
    Dim testArea As range
    Dim x As Integer
    With ActiveSheet
        Set testArea = range("D1").CurrentRegion
        For x = 1 To testArea.Columns.Count
            .range("ChartNum").Value = testArea.Columns(x).Value
            .ChartObjects(1).Chart.Refresh
            fixPieLabels .ChartObjects(1)
        Next x
    End With
End Sub
```

Anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it??  Why does a breakpoint cause it to calculate correctly?

**EDIT:** 
I tried to debug.print the calculation, and it is correct, so I tried assigning the calculation to a variable `newTop` and then setting the dataLabel `top` property to `newTop`...and it still has the wrong value! (And yes, the one I used this time is in a different bracket, so the calculation is different...

(`totSoFar` is simply a total of the values of the data points before this one, `thisPerc` is the value of this data point divided by `totSoFar`)

```
percOfSide = (totSoFar + thisPerc / 2) * 2
Debug.Print currLabel.Formula & " height: " & currLabel.Height
Debug.Print "percSide: " & percOfSide & " gT: " & grphTop & " gH: " & grphHeight
.....
ElseIf percOfSide > 0.75 Then
    Debug.Print ">75%-90%"
    Debug.Print "Answer: " & grphTop + percOfSide * grphHeight + currLabel.Height / 2
    newTop = grphTop + percOfSide * grphHeight + currLabel.Height / 2
end if
Debug.Print newTop
currLabel.Top = newTop
Debug.Print "postTop: " & currLabel.Top & " preLeft: " & currLabel.Left
```

And the printout:

```
Alternative Investments
2.000% height: 28.8554330708661
percSide: 0.88 gT: 82.5076377952756 gH: 153.454803149606
>75%-90%
Answer: 231.975580370633
231.975580370633 
postTop: 244.684251968504 preLeft: 278.302362204724
```

Comment: Are you changing worksheets while stepping through checking to make sure the code is working?  You might like to post your `fixPieLabels` procedure so we can help you fix the errors in it.  (Probably similar errors to the unqualified `Range("D1")` in the `testAll` procedure.)

Comment: I'm just wondering here, but wouldn't it make sense to use parenthesis or brackets around the formula you are using to make sure that you get the calculations right, because adding something to something before multiplying is not the same as multiplying and then adding something....

Comment: You're not showing us where `gT`, `currLabel.Height`, `percSide` and `gH` are being declared/assigned. We're supposed to guess?

Comment: @Mat's Mug - Sorry, `currLabel` is a dataLabel, so I'm not assigning or setting anything - I am simply getting the value from the VBA object.  `gT` is the plotArea.top, `gH` is the plotArea.height. `percSide` is a calculation, but since it has the same value in both cases (see the debug.print values), I don't see how the many lines of code I have are necessary to find the problem.  Basically, if I run the exact same thing but with a breakpoint set on one line, I get different results.  I can post the ENTIRE thing for you to read through, but it seems...excessive.

Comment: You claim a formula is giving different results in certain conditions, but you're not showing under what circumstances and how the involved values are assigned/modified. Don't need the whole code, but it's currently not possible to be sure of what's going on without editing some more code in.

Comment: @Mat's Mug - please see the Edit I just added.  I put in a snippet of code to show the calculation in line, along with the debug.print lines and the resulting debug.print info so you can see the values.  I added a "middle-man" variable, and the variable has the correct value (all of the variable values are in the debug.print, so you can calculate it out), but then after assigning the `currLabel.top` to that value, I debug.print the `currLabel.top`, and it is different from the value to which I JUST set it...

Comment: If `currLabel` is a data label, at some point you must set `currLabel` to the specific data label you are referring to.  To the best of my knowledge, VBA does not have a built-in object by that name.

Comment: @YowE3K - Yes, I `Set currLabel = .DataLabels(x)` at an earlier point in the macro.  It runs fine when I run it without the loop or if I have a breakpoint on the calling line in the loop.  Or, interestingly enough, without the breakpoint but with a second call to the sub in the same iteration of the loop, it runs correctly on the second time through the sub.

Comment: @YowE3K - Also, I am testing in a simple workbook with the chart, its data source, and all of the sets of values I want to test (Range("D1").currentRegion) all on the same worksheet, so no references to another sheet and the macro never activates another sheet.  I have two screens - VB Editor on one and spreadsheet on the other - so without leaving the Editor, I make no change except adding or removing the breakpoint on `fixPieLabels .ChartObjects(1)` in `testAll` and get different results.  Per the last test, it appears to be calculating correctly but not assigning to the property correctly

Comment: Do you happen to have removed "irrelevant" (note the quotes) `Select` and/or `Activate` calls?

Comment: @Mat's Mug - I don't use `Select` calls, and I don't activate anything in this macro.  Besides, the only change I have to make for it to run correctly is to add a breakpoint so the code pauses briefly, which is why I originally assumed the chart had simply not finished updating and was therefore producing incorrect results due to using old values. But debug.print showed it has the correct values and is calculating correctly, just not assigning to the property correctly unless it pauses briefly.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround right now is to simply set `currLabel.top = newTop` a second time immediately after, which works so far.  Hopefully it will also work on my client's computer!